# NgSPICE Too Few Parameters Error

Tags: simulation, spice

I have been trying to simulate a flash ADC in NGSPICE using the gEDA package. I had used the 74148 8 to 3 encoder and the UA741 OpAmp in the model. I had also included the requisite spice model files. However, when I compile the netlist in ngspice, i get the error:

Too few parameters for subcircuit type "74f148" (instance: xx2)

Can anyone help me here?

---

```
* gnetlist -g spice-sdb flash_Adc_NationalInstruments_eignd.sch
*********************************************************
* Spice file generated by gnetlist                      *
* spice-sdb version 4.28.2007 by SDB --                 *
* provides advanced spice netlisting capability.        *
* Documentation at http://www.brorson.com/gEDA/SPICE/   *
*********************************************************
*==============  Begin SPICE netlist of main design ============
*UA741 Signetics-TI Corporation
.INCLUDE ./models/UA741.inc
.INCLUDE ./models/74f.lib
R26 6 0 100  
R24 4 0 100  
R22 0 13 100  
R20 2 0 100  
R18 0 12 100  
V4 0 22 SIN(0 10 100kHz)
V2 21 0 100
X34 22 14 Vcc Vee 11 UA741
X32 22 15 Vcc Vee 10 UA741
X30 22 16 Vcc Vee 9 UA741
X28 22 17 Vcc Vee 8 UA741
X26 22 18 Vcc Vee 7 UA741
X24 22 19 Vcc Vee 5 UA741
X22 22 20 Vcc Vee 3 UA741
X20 22 21 Vcc Vee 1 UA741
R16 20 21 100  
R14 19 20 100  
R12 18 19 100  
R10 17 18 100  
R8 16 17 100  
R6 15 16 100  
R4 14 15 100  
R2 0 14 100  
X2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 13 74F148
.end
```

---

```
* 74F148  PRIORITY ENCODER 8-3 LINE
*
* FAST TTL LOGIC SERIES, 1990, PHILIPS SEMICONDUCTORS
* Freescale 2010 Model SN74148
* JLS   8-26-92   REMODELED USING LOGICEXP, PINDLY, AND CONSTRAINT DEVICES
*
.SUBCKT 74F148   IN0_I IN1_I IN2_I IN3_I IN4_I IN5_I IN6_I IN7_I EI_I
+ A0_O A1_O A2_O GS_O EO_O
+ OPTIONAL: DPWR=$G_DPWR DGND=$G_DGND
+ PARAMS: MNTYMXDLY=0 IO_LEVEL=0
*
UF148LOG LOGICEXP (9,14) DPWR DGND
+ IN0_I IN1_I IN2_I IN3_I IN4_I IN5_I IN6_I IN7_I EI_I
+ IN0   IN1   IN2   IN3   IN4   IN5   IN6   IN7   EI
+ A0 A1 A2 GS EO
+ D0_GATE IO_F
+ IO_LEVEL={IO_LEVEL}
+
+ LOGIC:
+ IN0    = { IN0_I }
+ IN1    = { IN1_I }
+ IN2    = { IN2_I }
+ IN3    = { IN3_I }
+ IN4    = { IN4_I }
+ IN5    = { IN5_I }
+ IN6    = { IN6_I }
+ IN7    = { IN7_I }
+ EI     = { EI_I }
+ IN0BAR = { ~IN0 }
+ IN1BAR = { ~IN1 }
+ IN2BAR = { ~IN2 }
+ IN3BAR = { ~IN3 }
+ IN4BAR = { ~IN4 }
+ IN5BAR = { ~IN5 }
+ IN6BAR = { ~IN6 }
+ IN7BAR = { ~IN7 }
+ EIBAR  = { ~EI }
+
+ A0     = { ~(EIBAR & ((IN1BAR & IN2 & IN4 & IN6) |
+                       (IN3BAR & IN4 & IN6) | (IN5BAR & IN6) | IN7BAR)) }
+ A1     = { ~(EIBAR & ((IN2BAR & IN4 & IN5) |
+                       (IN3BAR & IN4 & IN5) | IN6BAR | IN7BAR)) }
+ A2     = { ~(EIBAR & (IN4BAR | IN5BAR | IN6BAR | IN7BAR)) }
+ EO     = { ~(IN0 & IN1 & IN2 & IN3 & IN4 & IN5 & IN6 & IN7 & EIBAR) }
+ GS     = { ~(EO & EIBAR) }
*
UF148DLY PINDLY (5,0,9) DPWR DGND
+ A0 A1 A2 GS EO
+ IN0 IN1 IN2 IN3 IN4 IN5 IN6 IN7 EI
+ A0_O A1_O A2_O GS_O EO_O
+ IO_F
+ MNTYMXDLY={MNTYMXDLY} IO_LEVEL={IO_LEVEL}
+
+ BOOLEAN:
+   DATAHI   = { IN7=='1 & IN6=='1 & IN5=='1 & IN4=='1 &
+                IN3=='1 & IN2=='1 & IN1=='1 & IN0=='1 }
+   ENABLE   = { CHANGED(EI,0) }
+
+ PINDLY:
+   A2_O A1_O A0_O= {
+     CASE (
+       ENABLE & TRN_LH, DELAY(3.5NS,6.0NS, 9.5NS),
+       ENABLE & TRN_HL, DELAY(3.0NS,5.5NS, 9.0NS),
+                TRN_LH, DELAY(3.5NS,6.0NS,10.0NS),
+                TRN_HL, DELAY(4.0NS,6.0NS,12.0NS),
+       DELAY(4.0NS,6.0NS,12.0NS)
+       )
+     }
+   GS_O = {
+     CASE (
+       ENABLE & TRN_LH, DELAY(2.5NS,4.5NS, 8.0NS),
+       ENABLE & TRN_HL, DELAY(3.0NS,5.5NS, 8.5NS),
+                TRN_LH, DELAY(2.0NS,4.0NS,10.0NS),
+                TRN_HL, DELAY(2.0NS,6.0NS, 9.0NS),
+       DELAY(3.0NS,6.0NS,10.0NS)
+       )
+     }
+   EO_O = {
+     CASE (
+       ENABLE & TRN_LH, DELAY(3.0NS,5.0NS, 8.0NS),
+       ENABLE & TRN_HL, DELAY(4.5NS,7.0NS,12.0NS),
+                TRN_LH, DELAY(2.0NS,3.5NS, 7.5NS),
+                TRN_HL, DELAY(2.5NS,4.5NS, 8.5NS),
+       DELAY(4.5NS,7.0NS,12.0NS)
+       )
+     }
*
.ENDS
*
*$
```

Comment: If you don't share your deck, the best we can tell you is you didn't provide enough parameters when you instantaited the 74F148 subcircuit.

Comment: Added the pastebin docs to the question because one of them has a 30 day expiration on it and that would render the question useless in a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subcircuit begins with this card:

```
.SUBCKT 74F148   IN0_I IN1_I IN2_I IN3_I IN4_I IN5_I IN6_I IN7_I EI_I
+ A0_O A1_O A2_O GS_O EO_O
```

Notice, there are 14 connecting nodes, starting with `IN0_1` and ending with `E0_0`.

But when you instantiate the subcircuit, you use this X card:

```
X2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 13 74F148
```

This card tries to make 15 connections to the subcircuit, starting with `0` and ending with `13` (node `0` is connected twice).

The number of nodes assigned in the instantiation (X card) must match the number of connections called for by the subcircuit definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your 74F148 model is a generic SPICE model, it looks like it could be specific to PSPICE. You should check the manuals for ngspice to see if it supports the logic equations and delay statements.

Comment: Is there a resource library specific to ngspice? I have been looking for it and its very crucial for my project. Anyway, thanks for your help! :)